# Why RANKX is not ranking correctly, customer within category?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to rank my customers (by sum of sales) within catagories.
In addition, only showing Topn (through a visual filter) and being able to slice on customer.

Below my model

[My Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqmB7.png)

My DAX measures:

`_SUM = SUMX(Facts, Facts[FACT_VALUES])`

`Ranking = IF(ISINSCOPE(Customer[CUSTOMER]),RANKX (ALLSELECTED(Customer[CUSTOMER]), [_SUM],,desc,Dense))`

What's happening:

[Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUwJY.png)

It works **fine** when there is more than 1 customer in the slicer or when the visual filter is removed. Basically, this ONLY happens exactly in this situation, and only with a few customers.

It doesn't sound like a big deal but this could indicate a bigger problem, and I don't know why it's behaving as it is.

I've been trying to find out why for the better part of a week, and I've tried multiple columns in ALLSELECTED, wrapping RANKX in calculate, simplifying my data model, checking for NULLS/blanks, checking for relational integrity...